# Cannot view error output from move_uploaded_file() in php 5

Tags: php

I am testing an internal website with this code:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_array_name]['tmp_name'], $target))
       {
             some code......

             header("Refresh: 2; url=some url");
       }
       else
       {

           ini_set('display_errors', 1);
           ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
           error_reporting(-1);
           print_r(error_get_last());
           echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
       }
}
```

When I run it, I can see the echo statement but none of the errors.

Here's the settings for my php.ini:

```
php --info | grep "error"

    display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
    display_startup_errors => On => On
    error_append_string => no value => no value
    error_log => no value => no value
    error_prepend_string => no value => no value
    error_reporting => 24575 => 24575
    html_errors => Off => Off
```

The file that is causing the error is 305MB, and it works for smaller sized files.  So I was wondering if that was the error..

Here are some more values from php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 400M
upload_max_filesize = 400M
post_max_size = 400M
```

Comment: Try increasing the `max_input_time` and the `max_execution_time` too and see if it works

Comment: Argh, no luck there either

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `error_reporting(E_ALL);` after `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

However, this doesn't make PHP to show parse errors - the only way to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:

display_errors = on

ref: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)